# Composition of linear differential operators is a linear differential operator

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I will use multi-index notation:
$$ \newcommand{\p}{\partial} 
P = (p_1, \dots, p_d), |P| = p_1 + \dots + p_d,  \p^P u = \dfrac{\p ^{|P|} u}{\p x_1 ^{p_1} \dots \p x_d ^{p_d}} .$$
Let $A = \sum_{|P| \leq k} a_P(x) \p^P $ and $B = \sum_{|Q| \leq l} b_Q(x) \p^Q $ be two linear differential operators. I want to show its composition is still a linear differential operator.

How can I define $c_Z(x)$ to obtain $C$ a linear differential operator such that
$$ C(u) = \sum_{|Z| \leq k+l} c_Z(x) \p ^Z = A(B(u)) \quad ? $$

Answer (score 1):

In order to show that $A\circ B$ still is a linear differential operator, we only have to consider the case $A=\partial^P$ because if $D_1,D_2$ are two linear differential operators and $f_1,f_2$ two smooth functions, then $f_1D_1+f_2D_2$ is a linear differential operator. Indeed, write $D_1=\sum_{|P|\leqslant k}a_P\partial^P, D_2=\sum_{|Q|\leqslant l}b_Q\partial^Q$, then 
$$f_1D_1+f_2D_2=\sum_{|P|\leqslant k}f_1a_P\partial^P+\sum_{|Q|\leqslant l}f_2b_Q\partial^Q.$$
Define $m_i:=\min(k_i,l_i)$, $M_i:=\max(k_i,l_i)$ and $I^{(i)}_0=\{1,\dots,m_i\}$,  $I^{(i)}_1=\{m_i+1,\dots,M_i\}$ for $i\in [d]$. Then define for $J\subset \{0,1\}^d$ the subset $S_J:=\prod_{i=1}^dI^{(i)}_{J(i)}$. Then we can write the $2^d$ sums in order to express $f_1D_1+f_2D_2$ as a linear differential operator.

By a similar argument, we only have to deal with the case $B=h\partial^Q$.

We have in this case 
$$A\circ B(u)=\partial^P(h\partial^Q)(u)=\sum_{R\leqslant P}\binom PR\partial^{Q+R}(u)\partial^R(h).$$

Comment: What I don't understand is: why is $f_1 D_1 + f_2 D_2$ still a linear differential operator?

Comment: I've edited. It's indeed quite technical.

Comment: Actually it's trivial, if I'm not omitting anything: if $A = \sum_{|P| \leq k} a_P \p^P$ and $B = \sum_{|P| \leq l} b_P \p^P$, then $A+B = C$ where $$C = \sum_{P \leq \max (k,l)} c_P \p^P$$ and $$c_P = a_P + b_P,$$ where eventually $a_P = 0$ or $b_P= 0$ when not defined.

Comment: What was misleading me however was a wrong application of Leibniz rule, which now I've removed.